# Fit Gaussian to Histogram in Log Scale using Matplotlib

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I have some data in a numpy array, data = [], where I want to make a histogram with a Gaussian fit of the data.  The difference over usual is, however, I want to do this with the y axis in log scale.  How do I do this?  I can currently get the histogram/fit just fine if I normalize, and can get the histogram in log space, but have not found a subsequent way to plot a Gaussian fit when in log space.  I did find one potential method online, logpdf (instead of much more commonly used normpdf), but when I try the code below I get "TypeError: unbound method logpdf() must be called with rv_continuous instance as first argument (got ndarray instance instead)", and I confess this doesn't make sense to me even after seeing what Google had to say.  I'm happy to use whatever method though, as long as the y axis is log scaled.

Thank you very much in advance!

```
from scipy.stats import norm
from scipy.stats import rv_continuous

import matplotlib.mlab as mlab
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as plt

num, bins = np.histogram(data,n_bins)
len(data)
n_bins = 50

(mu, sigma) = norm.fit(data)


n, bins, patches = plt.hist(data, n_bins, color='r', alpha=.75)

# add a 'best fit' line
y = rv_continuous.logpdf(bins, mu, sigma)


plt.plot(bins, mlab.normpdf(bins, mu,sigma), label="gaus fit", lw=3)
plt.plot(bins, logpdf(bins, mu,sigma), label="gaus fit", lw=3)
plt.xlabel('Flux (Jy)')
plt.ylabel('Count (normed)')
plt.yscale('log', nonposy='clip')

plt.show()
```

Comment: You should always post the complete Traceback.

Comment: Instead of ```plt.plot(bins, logpdf(bins, mu,sigma), ...``` why don't you use ```plt.plot(bins, y)....``` since it is already calculated??

Comment: If you believe your data is drawn from a gaussian, why don't you get estimates of the mean and variance from the sample mean and variance? Or if you want to fit a gaussian curve to the discrete values from the histogram bins, why not use a least squared optimisation?

Comment: Hi, sorry, if someone is still reading this... complete traceback is 

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-32-7b90ab53a504> in <module>()
     13 # add a 'best fit' line
     14 y = mlab.normpdf(bins, mu, sigma)
---> 15 y = rv_continuous.logpdf(bins, mu, sigma)
     16 plt.plot(bins, y, 'b--', lw=2)
     17 

TypeError: unbound method logpdf() must be called with rv_continuous instance as first argument (got ndarray instance instead)

I thus cant use the calculated values, because the correct ones aren't calculated for my plot.